# Does ion damage penetrate shields?

Tags: star-wars-x-wing

In X-Wing, there are several ships (such as the Y-Wing) which use ion canons.

The description says:

> If this attack hits the target ship, the ship suffers 1 damage and
>   receives 1 ion token. Then cancel **all** dice results.

Assuming the target ship has shields is the damage dealt to the target ship's shields or it's hull?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No, Ion Damage is handled as normal, plus an Ion token**

This is addressed in the [core rules](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/x-wing/support/SWX01_XwingCoreRulebook_lowres.pdf) on page 16 under the heading "Suffering Damage":

> When a ship suffers damage or critical damage, it suffers them **one at a time** following these steps. ...
>   1. **Reduce Shields:** If there are any shield tokens remaining on the ship's card, remove one of the tokens and skip Step 2. ...

*(Emphasis theirs)*

The rules for receiving damage are separate from the rules for dealing damage, so unless the card specifically states that it bypasses shields, the targeted ship would receive the 1 point of damage following the normal rules.